# Combining two lists together in Matplotlib Text Class with sorting

Tags: python, list, sorting, matplotlib, text

So basically around 2019 matplotlib developers decided, if you like to get the x-axis minor ticks, they do not want to give you the minor ticks if they overlap with the major ticks. However I need to have all of it.

```
x_minor_labels = [i for i in ax.xaxis.get_minorticklabels()]
x_minor_extras = [i for i in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()]
```

Output is:

```
(Pdb) x_minor_labels
[Text(18263.0, 0, '02'), Text(18264.0, 0, '03'), Text(18265.0, 0, '04'), Text(18266.0, 0, '05'), 
 Text(18267.0, 0, '06'), Text(18268.0, 0, '07'), Text(18269.0, 0, '08'), Text(18270.0, 0, '09'), 
 Text(18271.0, 0, '10'), Text(18272.0, 0, '11'), Text(18273.0, 0, '12'), Text(18274.0, 0, '13'), 
 Text(18275.0, 0, '14'), Text(18277.0, 0, '16'), Text(18278.0, 0, '17'), Text(18279.0, 0, '18'), 
 Text(18280.0, 0, '19'), Text(18281.0, 0, '20'), Text(18282.0, 0, '21'), Text(18283.0, 0, '22'), 
 Text(18284.0, 0, '23'), Text(18285.0, 0, '24'), Text(18286.0, 0, '25'), Text(18287.0, 0, '26'), 
 Text(18288.0, 0, '27'), Text(18289.0, 0, '28'), Text(18290.0, 0, '29'), Text(18291.0, 0, '30'), 
 Text(18292.0, 0, '31'), Text(18294.0, 0, '02'), Text(18295.0, 0, '03'), Text(18296.0, 0, '04'), 
 Text(18297.0, 0, '05'), Text(18298.0, 0, '06'), Text(18299.0, 0, '07'), Text(18300.0, 0, '08'), 
 Text(18301.0, 0, '09'), Text(18302.0, 0, '10'), Text(18303.0, 0, '11'), Text(18304.0, 0, '12'), ...]
(Pdb) x_minor_extras
[Text(18262.0, 0, '01'), Text(18276.0, 0, '15'), Text(18293.0, 0, '01'), 
 Text(18307.0, 0, '15'), Text(18322.0, 0, '01'), Text(18336.0, 0, '15')]
```

As you can see some of the `x_minor_labels` are missing, because they overlap with `x_minor_extras` 's Text Class first attribute in our case `18262.0`.

What I want to do is now combine those to lists which contains Text Class with sorting so that `x_minor_extras`'s first element will be the first element of the new list, and then comes the first element of the `x_minor_labels`

Some helper functions I found:

```
x_minor_extras[0].get_text()
'01'

x_minor_extras[0].set_text('lalala')
x_minor_extras[0].get_text()
'lalala'
```

**Expected Outcome:**

```
new_list
[Text(18262.0, 0, '01'), Text(18263.0, 0, '02'), Text(18264.0, 0, '03'), Text(18265.0, 0, '04'), 
 Text(18266.0, 0, '05'), Text(18267.0, 0, '06'), Text(18268.0, 0, '07'), Text(18269.0, 0, '08'), 
 Text(18270.0, 0, '09'), Text(18271.0, 0, '10'), Text(18272.0, 0, '11'), Text(18273.0, 0, '12'), 
 Text(18274.0, 0, '13'), Text(18275.0, 0, '14'), Text(18262.0, 0, '15'), Text(18277.0, 0, '16'), ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```py
def mysort(ele): 
    return ele.get_text()

print(sorted(x_minor_labels+x_minor_extras, key=mysort))
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because the only way to reach the position number is `x_minor_extras[0].get_unitless_position()[0]`

Comment: then use `return ele.get_unitless_position()[0]` in `mysort` function

Answer (score 0):

**BEST WORK AROUND:**

basically change the matplotlib source file in conda environment. To get all the ticks when you call `get_minorticklabels()`

```
D:\Anaconda3\envs\<your_env_name>\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py
```

**CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINE TO FALSE**

```
self._remove_overlapping_locs = True
```

This is somehow added in a commit, so that people still can have this option.

This was the issue https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13618/

And this was the commit https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/e3a83931ea42980a05e93741a44b1c7c6481da5f

---

Well, I found out how to do:

```
x_minor_labels = [i for i in ax.xaxis.get_minorticklabels()]
x_minor_extras = [i for i in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()]

for i in range(0, len(x_minor_extras)):
    counter = 0
    for j in range(0, len(x_minor_labels)):
        counter += 1
        if (x_minor_extras[i].get_unitless_position()[0] < 
            x_minor_labels[j].get_unitless_position()[0]):
            x_minor_labels.insert(counter-1, x_minor_extras[i])
            break
        else:
            pass
```